# C struct initialization and pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct hello{
  int id;
}hello;

void modify(hello *t);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  hello t1;
  modify(&t1);
  printf("%d\n", t1.id);
  return 0;
}

void modify(hello *t)
{
  t = (hello*)malloc(sizeof(hello));
  t->id = 100;
}
```

Why doesn't the program output `100`? Is it a problem with `malloc`? I have no idea to initialize the struct.

How can I get desired output by editing `modify` only?

Comment: 1) do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) Please think for yourself for a moment: you pass a value to `t` in your function and instantly overwrite this by the `malloc`. So, what use would passing the value have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void modify(hello *t)
{
  t = (hello*)malloc(sizeof(hello));
  t->id = 100;
}
```

should be

```
void modify(hello *t)
{
  t->id = 100;
}
```

Memory is already statically allocated to `h1` again you are creating memory on heap and writing to it.

So the address passed to the function is overwritten by `malloc()`
The return address of `malloc()` is some memory on heap and not the address the object `h1` is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Initially pointer t was pointing to address of t1, later in modify function, pointer t was pointing to the memory returned by the malloc.

t->id = 100; was initializing the memory returned by malloc, hence you are not seeing this getting reflected in the main when

printf("%d\n", t1.id);

is executed.